# Why can I not use format function while Jet-SQL to T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I was trying to convert one of my MS Access query containing format to a SQL Server view. I have my view connected to MS Access as linked tables. I was looking at [this](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/03/30/quick-access-jet-sql-to-t-sql-cheatsheet/) MS Access to SQL server cheat-sheet to convert Jet-SQL to T-SQL.

The cheat sheet says:

> Access:     SELECT Format(Value, FormatSpecification)  (note: this
>   always returns a string value)
>
> T-SQL:      **Do not do this in T-SQL;
>   format data at your front-end application or report**

I cannot format data at my front end because the SQL Server view is linked as linked tables. I cannot have format function in tables.

The cheat sheet does not provide any explanation on why not to do this in T-SQL.

What is the reason behind not using format when converting Jet-SQL to T-SQL?

Comment: I'd guess it is just _generally_ that this type of formatting is well suited to something in the user interface rather than when you query it from the database. Of course you can format values when you query though too. It just depends on the datatype you are querying, and how you want to display it (e.g. dates, numeric data, currency values etc etc). If you have a specific need, just search for the T-SQL instructions via your favourite search engine and you'll find what you need.

Comment: If you post DDL and your portion of code in MS-Access maybe somebody can find a way of doing the same in SQL.

Comment: You can format the date on the access client side. Create a client side (access) query. Use the view as the source for that query, and add the column with the format as you please. And if it is a report, or form, then simply place the format in that bound control access side. Just about ANY choice you make to display data client side will involve a form, or report - so you don't even have to create a query on the view, but simply move the formatting to the control in question. However, as noted, you can also just create a query in Access based on that view, and do the formatting in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you *can* format values in T-SQL using the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function, which only has minor differences with the Access format function.

Generally, though, you shouldn't.

There are multiple reasons why it's discouraged:

1. Formatted strings are nearly always larger than unformatted dates/numbers, causing additional overhead when transmitting results
2. If you format in the application layer, the unformatted value is available to you in the application layer to validate/do calculations with/use for conditional formatting/etc. If you format in the data in the database layer, you can't do this without casting back to a date (which is a really bad practice).
3. If you want variable formatting based on things like locale settings, it's *way* easier to format in the application layer.

It's certainly not a limitation of SQL Server. It's just a bad practice to use it.

Comment: For 2. also: Sorting (for dates or numbers).